# Getting initial catalog from the web.config file

Tags: find, connection-string

I have a connection string in the web.config file. I have to get the database name from it.
Let say my connection sting is

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I want to get the database name [i.e. Initial Catalog] from the connection string.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for this purpose:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string database = builder.InitialCatalog;
```

Comment: Perfect ! I never knew that .NET has such feature too.

Comment: Is it possible to get connection string name as strongly typed name, so I don't have to use string as name ?